# Update Records in SQL

Tags: sql, replace, sql-update

I have database I can't figure out how to update a column because it's on a table that is generated per call. Here is the code to call the column in question:

```
select 
    a.itm_num as item_no,
    a.itm_proddesc as title,
    CAST(d.content as varchar(max)) as product_description
from item as a
join assignment as b on b.itm_id = a.itm_id
join attachment as c on c.att_id = b.att_id
join digitalassetcontent as d on d.content_key = c.content_key
where c.att_type like 'text%'
```

I need to update the product_description field. We have thousands of entrys in this column that have HTML coding in front of the actual text. I need to run a find and replace to remove the html coding before the text. The HTML code before each text is exactly the same, here is what needs to be removed: `<STYLE>H1{font-weight:bold}H1{font-size: 14pt}OL</STYLE><H1>Product Description</H1>`

I ran the following code with @Joel Coehoorn solution with the content key I need to update and it kicked back an error of 'Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
The multi-part identifier "d.content" could not be bound.'

```
select 
    a.itm_num as item_no,
    a.itm_proddesc as title,
    CAST(d.content as varchar(max)) as product_description
from item as a
join assignment as b on b.itm_id = a.itm_id
join attachment as c on c.att_id = b.att_id
join digitalassetcontent as d on d.content_key = c.content_key
where c.att_type like 'text%'

Update digitalassetcontent
set content = replace(CAST(content as varchar(max)), '<STYLE>H1{font-weight:bold}H1{font-size: 14pt}OL</STYLE><H1>Product Description</H1>','')
where CAST(content as varchar(max)) like '<STYLE>H1{font-weight:bold}H1{font-size: 14pt}OL</STYLE><H1>Product Description</H1>%' AND content_key = 'desc214974236480438500781058983745755010'
```

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 1):

That's just the `digitalassetcontent.content` field. You should be able to just act on the field directly. What is the actual type of that field?

```
Update digitalassetcontent
set content = replace(CAST(d.content as varchar(max)), '<STYLE>H1{font-weight:bold}H1{font-size: 14pt}OL</STYLE><H1>Product Description</H1>','')
where CAST(d.content as varchar(max)) like '<STYLE>H1{font-weight:bold}H1{font-size: 14pt}OL</STYLE><H1>Product Description</H1>%'
```

Comment: The actual type of field is varbinary and the max character length says -1

Just so I can test first and make sure everything is kosher, how would I run your code above just on a certain item number and not all the items? Let's use item number 'AA100' for example, the column name is called 'item_no' which is generated in teh intial call in my first post.

Comment: @MattWeick I'd look up the specific content key you want to test against, rather than the item number.

Comment: If you need help with that, you might want to take a step back from the database.

Comment: Okay, I did some digging and the specific content key I need to update is 'desc214974236480438500781058983745755010'

Comment: I have made edits to my original post please see update above.

Comment: @MattWeick: You need to get rid of the two references to "d" in your UPDATE statement. They are not needed in the context of that SQL. That is what the SQL exception is referring to.

Comment: @Ellesedil: I took out the two references to "d" in the UPDATE and it kicked back this error: 'Implicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.'